# JNI GetStringUTFChars called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchFieldError

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mupdf

I use `mupdf` in the following code in my project:

```
public MuPDFCore(String filename) throws Exception
    {
        if (openFile(filename) <= 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to open "+filename);
        }
    }
```

But when I run it, I get the following error. Has anyone come across this problem?

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetStringUTFChars called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "J" field "globals" in class "Ljava/lang/Class;" or its superclasses  
>   03-07 02:58:17.064 2500-2500/com.xinhui.electronicsignature A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at long com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFCore.openFile(java.lang.String) (MuPDFCore.java:-2)
>   03-07 02:58:17.064 2500-2500/com.xinhui.electronicsignature A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at void com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFCore.(java.lang.String) (MuPDFCore.java:40)
>   03-07 02:58:17.064 2500-2500/com.xinhui.electronicsignature A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFCore com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity.Openfile1(java.lang.String) (MuPDFActivity.java:189)
>   03-07 02:58:17.064 2500-2500/com.xinhui.electronicsignature A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at void com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MuPDFActivity.java:228)
>   03-07 02:58:17.064 2500-2500/com.xinhui.electronicsignature A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6237)
>   03-07 02:58:17.064 2500-2500/com.xinhui.electronicsignature A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1107)

Comment: Welcome to SO. To solve this problem we need to see your code. You can use the edit function to add the code that caused this problem to the question. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to increase your chance of answers.

Comment: Thanks,I reedited the problem，i am first time ask questions，so I don't know a lot of rules@m00am

Comment: No problem :) You question already looks a lot better. I also added the mupdf and java tags which might catch the attention of people who know how to solve this.

Comment: Thank you!@m00am

Comment: The problem is that you had an undetected exception last time you called `GetFieldID()` and continued to execute your JNI code. You can't do that. You must check *every JNU call* for an error, and *not* continue if you get one. This is all described very clearly in the JNI Specification.

Answer (score 0):

I have problem exactly as your problem. But when I create new project, and put these code into new project, it still work fine.

I dont know why this could happend. First, I think it about JDK version between 2 project (current & test project), but nothing change.

Finally, I compile MuPDF with version 1.10 (old version is 1.9), replace .so file . And it worked.

I think something wrong with C class. That's all.

**UPDATED:
I solve my problem**

```
#ifdef NDK_PROFILER
    monstartup("libmupdf_java32.so");
#endif

    clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, thiz);
    if (clazz == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    global_fid = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, clazz, "globals", "J");
    if (global_fid == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    glo = calloc(1, sizeof(*glo));
    if (glo == NULL)
        return 0;
    glo->resolution = 160;
    glo->alerts_initialised = 0;
```

make sure **globals** filed in

```
global_fid = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, clazz, "globals", "J");
```

match with field in your Java class.

```
    private long globals;
```

"J" in JNI is long type in java.

Finally, make sure remove proguard in build.gradle

```
    buildTypes {
//        debug {
//            shrinkResources true
//            minifyEnabled true
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), "proguard-rules.pro"
//        }

        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }

    }
```

Or you can using **keep** in proguard file. "minifyEnabled" make **globals** change when you build app.

Comment: It worked because of your `if (global_fid == NULL)` test. OP didn't have that so he continued execution to the next thing, which found the pending exception and barfed.

Comment: @user207421 check null in JNI to make sure even if can't find **globals**, app will not crash.  In my case, problem is about proguard. when i remove check null, it work fine.